# Linked list. How can i delete first node in my list?

Tags: c++

I need do delete nodes in my original list which value is equal to node values in second list and then I need to return updated original list. I deleted (at least I think I did) first node in my list, but when i call the function and then try to print the updated List, program constantly prints 4 random numbers. Delete function works with every other node but not with the first one.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int x;
    Node* next;
};

Node* createNode(int x){
    Node* node=new Node();
    node->x=x;
    node->next=NULL;
    return node;
}

Node* createList(){
    int i,n;
    Node* head=NULL,*p=NULL;
    cout<<"How many nodes: ";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i==0){
            head=new Node();
            p=head;
        }
        else{
            p->next=new Node();
            p=p->next;
        }
        cout<<"Insert value of a node: ";
        cin>>p->x;
    }
    return head;
}

void printList(Node* head){
    cout<<"Values of nodes in a List: "<<endl;
    while(head!=NULL){
        cout<<head->x<<"   ";
        head=head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

Node* deleteNodes(Node* head,Node* head2){
    Node* temp1=NULL,*p=NULL,*pret=NULL;
    while(head2!=NULL){//1 NULL
        p=head;
        while(p!=NULL){// 1 NULL
            temp1=p->next;
            if(head->x==head2->x){
                pret=head;
                head=pret->next;
                p=head;
                delete pret;
                pret=NULL;
            }
            if(temp1==NULL) break;
            else if(temp1->x==head2->x){
                p->next=temp1->next;
                delete temp1;
            }
            else p=p->next;
        }
        head2=head2->next;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(){
    Node* head=NULL,*head2=NULL;
    head=createList();
    head2=createList();
    cout<<"List 1"<<endl;
    printList(head);
    cout<<"List 2"<<endl;
    printList(head2);
    cout<<"///////////////"<<endl;
    deleteNodes(head,head2);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Example: 
Original List(1,2,3,4,5)
Second List(1,2,3)
Expected result of updated List: (4,5)
My result:

> 9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   9311504 9306448 9328768 9311504
>   ...

Comment: Pass the pointers by reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new head of the list is the value returned from the function, and your old `head` is invalid since whatever it used to point to has been destroyed.

Write `head = deleteNodes(head,head2);` and you should see your dreams come true.

(Related: assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument has no effect outside the function. Pointers are not special.)